# Bash: Rename command not working on subdirectories when used with find

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following command that removes the first occurrence of '|' from the names of files and replaces it with '!'.

```
rootcmd -s sh -c "find . -type f | grep '|' | rename '|' '!' *"
```

It works fine when run from the same directory as the files it manipulates. Let's call this the child directory. However, I have a parent directory with multiple child directories. When I run it from the parent directory, rename doesn't work. I want it to traverse all the child directories and do the same operation. The interesting things is, I know that the first part of the command (minus the rename) works:

```
rootcmd -s sh -c "find . -type f | grep '|'"
```

The above would return all files in all child directories with '|' in the filename. However, when I append the rename command, it does not rename the files as intended.

Any linux/bash gurus out there that can explain or fix this?

Comment: `rename` doesn't read from stdin, or does it? If you want to act in each directory, `find . -type d -exec sh -c 'cd "$1" || exit 1; rename "|" "!" *' _ {} \;`

Comment: By the way, don't parse the output of `find` unless you take extreme precautions. And we all love the [Learning Toothpick Syndrome](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) `:)`

Comment: AHH, no I guess it does not read from stdin. That explains it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. Instead of `rename something something *`, you need to pass in the output of find using xargs, like this:

```
rootcmd -s sh -c "find . -type f | grep '|' | xargs rename '|' '!'"
```